# Spring Boot API on vServer not responding

Tags: java, spring-boot, server

I want my Spring Boot Application to run on a vServer and not only from my local machine.
So I rented a vServer which is available under http://81f32c8.online-server.cloud/.
After that I ran my build Spring Boot App on the server with `java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod ./app.jar`

And Spring Boot started successfully:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.8)

2023-10-10 15:42:49.906  INFO 5279 --- [           main] com.example.system.SystemApplication     : Starting SystemApplication using Java 11.0.20.1 on localhost with PID 5279 (/root/app.jar started by root in /root)
2023-10-10 15:42:49.915  INFO 5279 --- [           main] com.example.system.SystemApplication     : The following 1 profile is active: "prod"
2023-10-10 15:42:52.870  INFO 5279 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-10-10 15:42:53.150  INFO 5279 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 247 ms. Found 8 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-10-10 15:42:55.298  INFO 5279 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-10-10 15:42:55.337  INFO 5279 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-10-10 15:42:55.337  INFO 5279 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.63]
2023-10-10 15:42:55.593  INFO 5279 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-10-10 15:42:55.593  INFO 5279 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5513 ms
2023-10-10 15:42:56.757  WARN 5279 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-10-10 15:42:57.173  INFO 5279 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-10-10 15:42:57.366  INFO 5279 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.9.Final
2023-10-10 15:42:57.940  INFO 5279 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2023-10-10 15:42:58.313  INFO 5279 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-10-10 15:42:58.538  INFO 5279 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-10-10 15:42:58.651  INFO 5279 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB106Dialect
2023-10-10 15:43:00.963  INFO 5279 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-10-10 15:43:00.995  INFO 5279 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-10-10 15:43:06.896  INFO 5279 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@60c1663c, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@42aae04d, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6419a0e1, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@f5cf29b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@16a35bd, com.example.system.security.jwt.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter@3f9f71ff, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@575e572f, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7426a448, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3c66b7d8, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@56b859a6, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6ed043d3, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@24a2e565]
2023-10-10 15:43:07.854  INFO 5279 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-10-10 15:43:07.891  INFO 5279 --- [           main] com.example.system.SystemApplication     : Started SystemApplication in 19.602 seconds (JVM running for 21.136)
```

But when I try to reach my get endpoint `/api/v1/instrument/list` with `http://81f32c8.online-server.cloud/api/v1/instrument/list` I got no response.

Has someone an idea what I forgot?
Do I have to configure the tomcat webserver somehow?